# How to select a set of values in pandas data frame (multiple colums with multiple row conditions)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a huge ass csv file like given below which I opened as dataframe using pandas. I want to extract data from multiple columns at different date sets.

I want to select from a particular date and hour to another for the last 3 column values. The slicing options I tried and googled were for single column.

```
            date  heure PM10 NO2  O3

  0  01/01/2016      1   27  22  36

  1  01/01/2016      2   25  29  27

  2  01/01/2016      3   26  47  10

  3  01/01/2016      4   16  40  13

  4  01/01/2016      5   15  34  13

  5  02/01/2016      1   15  34  13

  6  02/01/2016      2   15  34  13
```

Target output - taking data from a particular data and hour to another one.

```
  3  01/01/2016      4   16  

  4  01/01/2016      5   15
```

Thank you. The data set is obviously way bigger than 4 No.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to accomplish. What is your target output?

Comment: @Joe I just updated post with target output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df_selected = df[(df.date >= "01/01/2016") & 
                 (df['hour']>=4)            &
                 (df.date < "02/01/2016")  &
                 (df['hour']<6)            
                ].iloc[:,:3] #first three columns
```

Alternatively, for the columns selection you can use `.loc[:,['name', 'of', 'columns']]` or for the last n columns `.iloc[:,-n:]`.
Be careful with date because I'm not sure what happens with an "English" date, maybe you have to change the date using `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)`.

Comment: Thank you. I want to select from a particular date and time till another one. Do you have a work around on that?

Comment: With > and < it does not work? 
df[(df.date >= date1) & 
                 (df['hour']>=hour1)            &
                 (df.date < date2)  &
                 (df['hour']<hour2)            
                ].iloc[:,:3] #first three columns

Comment: Yes, it works for those two values, but not if there are multiple rows to be selected. I think if we replace '&' with something that works as 'to' it might work. I don't know how though.

Comment: The "to" is not given by & but by <. With that, you are selecting those rows that have a date greater that date1 and less than date2. If in date2 you put "03/01/2016" it will select also the one with date "02/01/2016" - but in your example you have to change the hours because that code only consider hours between [4,6). Maybe I didn't understand your request. Can you do another example with the data above?

Comment: Thank you. My requirement was simple sorting as we do in excel. I want to select a particular column values from one row to another of my preference. For some reason I am unable to figure it out.